# Packaging a pre-populated SQLite database with my Android App

Tags: android, database, sqlite, pre-packaged

I'm a beginner in Android programming, fairly well experienced in Java. I'm using Android Studio with KitKate and Lollipop Emus and HW, developing for Froyo. I want to know what's presently the best accepted and easiest to implement way of including a database with my Android App.

I've looked at ActiveAndroid, but I followed their documentation exactly and found I was far from the only person to struggle with it's implementation - even the best programmers I know told me I was flogging a dead horse.

A very commonly posted link is this: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

It's 6 years old, and I'd rather follow today's best practises.

TIA,

TH

[Edit]

I've explained that this question is with regards as to whether the ReignDesign post is still acceptable, and, or, if there are any other better resources or libraries one can use that make this very common task as easy as it should be.

Comment: I've explained that this question is with regards as to whether the ReignDesign post is still acceptable, and, or, if there are any other better resources or libraries one can use that make this very common task as easy as it should be.

Comment: (This is my way of saying "yes".)

Comment: (Well, to what part of my edit are you saying yes to? This is what happens when a discussion is closed before it's even begun...)

Comment: The blog post is ancient and the code there does not work well. Consider sqlite-asset-helper also linked in the dupe target.

Comment: I have found this in regards to SQLiteAssetHelper: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/using-a-database-with-your-android-app

I do not see why users consider my original post to be considered a duplicate when it's topic of discussion is whether those posts I'm supposedly duplicating are still reccomend.

Comment: SO has this problem where crusty old answers are still considered correct, but often are not, since technology moves on.  I also think a "modern" response to this question would be nice.  I don't consider this a duplicate, but reviewers tend to get all excited, flexing muscles, when they find something similar.   Your best bet in this situation is reference the supposed duplicates directly in your question and explain specifically what they are NOT answering.